# Ember.js previous/next element of an array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to make a queue-like array, and I don't know how to move to the next element. I'm not using a for loop to iterate, because if the element of the array is deleted there is a problem.

What Can I do?

EDIT:
I should put an example code:
Creating array in a controller:

```
listOfItems:[{name:'Jack',specialty:'engineer'},{name:"Eva",speciality:"doctor"}]
```

next setting the values to the handlebars

```
counter:0,
actions:{
    openModal()
    {
        this.set('openModal',true);
        this.set('nameOfPerson',this.get('listOfItems.'+counter+'.name');
    }
    nextValue()
    {
         this.incrementProperty('counter'); //I want to implement there
                                            //something like next Object
    }
    previousValue()
    {
        this.decrementProperty('counter'); //  previous object there
    }
    acceptValues()
    {
        //don't know how to do a delete object there
    }
}
```

Comment: some code might be useful to better understand your problem

Comment: Of course, I should put a code at the beginning, greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use a new property for this, something like this.

```
counter: 0,
currentItem: function() {
    return this.get('listOfItems').objectAt(this.get('counter'));
}.property('counter', 'listOfItems.[]')
actions:{
    openModal() {
        this.set('openModal',true);
        this.set('nameOfPerson',this.get('currentItem.name');
    },
    acceptValues() {
        let counter = this.get('counter');

        this.get('listOfItems').removeAt(counter); // Assumes an Ember.MutableArray

        if(counter > 0) {
            // If we are at the first item, just let the second value be selected,
            // if any other value is removed, decrement the counter by one to select
            // the previous item
            this.decrementProperty('counter');
        }
    }        
}
```

This way you could also directly bind to `currentItem` in your template if needed, so `nameOfPerson` could possibly be avoided and `currentItem.name` used instead.

The `acceptValues` method simply removes the item from the array and decrements `counter` is possible. The `currentItem` property would be invalidated since it depends on `listOfItems.[]` (ie update when the number of items changes).

Comment: That's exactly what i need, especially the removeAt function, and the currentItem function, thank You and greetings